# How to send user define object to other activity

Tags: android

I want to send user define object from one activity to another in android application.

I have created user class object and send this user object to my second activity from first activity.

Comment: yes, implementing class to Parcelable interface it;s working

Comment: @ChetanChaudhari please check y answer below. try using Parcelable.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your class with **Serializable** interface.
Then pass the object using

```
intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);
```

and retrieve object by calling

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your `User` class implements `Parcelable`.

   ```
   public class User implements Parcelable {

       ...........
       ............... 
   }
   ```
2. Send `User` object to `SecondActivity` as below:

   ```
   User userObject = new User();

   Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("user_data", userObject);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. Retrieving the `User` object in `SecondActivity`.

   ```
   User user = (User) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("user_data");
   ```

Here is good [Tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable) about using `Parcelable`.

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

Iplemented my user define class to Parcelable interface.